# How to choose cells from a table to maximize their sum, with selection constraints?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, heuristics

I have a table of fixed positive integer values of anything up to several dozen.  There are six columns and several hundred rows.  I must choose exactly two values from each column, and zero or one value from each row, for a total of twelve cells selected.  Having chosen them, their values are summed for a total score.  Higher scores are better than lower ones.

Difficulty:  the values in a row are somewhat correlated, so quite often the rows having the highest values in a column will also have the highest values in one or more other columns.  Since no more than one value can be chosen per row, only one column can "win" the desirable row and the rest have to "make do with" another.

1. Is there an algorithm better than brute force for choosing the best combination (or an arbitrary one of the best combinations in the case of ties)?
2. What fast heuristics can get "pretty close"?